# How to change Alert Direction into RTL in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there any way to change `alert direction` in ionic 2 ?

```
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'خطأ',
          subTitle: 'GPS والوصول إلى الشبكة غير ممكن.',
          enableBackdropDismiss: false,
          buttons: [{
            text: 'نعم',
            handler: () => {
              setTimeout(() => this.locate(), 1500);
            }
          }],
        });
```

I tried and tested some css  but fails.

Answer (score 1):

I try but have a difficult way for change this.
Try use [ionic AlertController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/)
And set enableBackdropDismiss:false for work like alertCtrl

Comment: I used platform.setDir('rtl', true); .